# No module named 'new_app' Django 1.8 error

Tags: python, django

I am deploying new django `new_app` with the command django-admin.py startapp `new_app`, add it to installed apps in `settings.py` . Then after `makemigrations` and `migrate`  commands everything is fine. Now I need to copy files from GitHub and replace default `new_app` folder with them.

I delete everything from `new_app` folder exept default migrations (is this right?) and delete migrations from the relevant cloned GitHub folder and copy everything else to new_app folder. So, the only thing left dafault is migrations.

After those actions `makemirgations` command responds with the following traceback:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/django/django_project/denv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/django/django_project/denv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/django/django_project/denv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/django/django_project/denv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/django/django_project/denv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named `new_app`
```

Comment: have you deleted __init__.py? Thats what recognises a folder as a module in python.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar nope, just replaced with the same default init.py. there is no difference between them

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar you were right, I don't understand why but original init makes it work

Comment: post the content of the `__init__.py` file then